# Macro that compares an unknown number of variables C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a macro that will compare a user specified amount of variables, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

//compares x to only a and b
#define equalTo(x, a, b) x != a && x != b 

int main()
{
    int x;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "x = ";
        std::cin >> x;
    } while (equalTo(x, 1, 2));  //I wanna input as many as i want to be compared to "x"
    //for example i want equalTo(x, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to work too, without a new macro

    std::cout << "x = " << x;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm kind of stuck, having no idea where to go with this.

Comment: Why doesn't it show my "Hello, world" at the beginning of the question, it just starts from "I'm trying..."... weird...

Comment: Do you want `equal to` or `not equal to`?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, that's not the problem :P

Comment: @sasauke: StackOverflow isn't a forum, but a Q&A site. Apparently the AI is now removing non-question parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with macros but *variadic templates* offers a solution:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<typename X, typename Arg>
bool notEqualTo(X x, Arg arg)
{
    return x != arg;
}

template<typename X, typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool notEqualTo(X x, Arg arg, Args... args)
{
    return notEqualTo(x, arg) && notEqualTo(x, args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int x = std::rand() % 10;
        int a = std::rand() % 10;
        int b = std::rand() % 10;
        int c = std::rand() % 10;

        std::cout << x << ": (" << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ") ";
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << notEqualTo(x, a, b, c) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5: (9, 8, 0) true
7: (4, 3, 4) true
1: (3, 2, 5) true
7: (4, 7, 0) false
8: (9, 9, 8) false
5: (8, 4, 4) true
9: (9, 9, 4) false
8: (8, 6, 3) false
7: (4, 5, 4) true
0: (1, 0, 4) false
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I had never heard of variadic templates before. I guess I'll have to look into them!!

Comment: Way better than macro's. You can pass expressions to them. Your macro would break if you'd pass `7 && false, 8` whereas the template function would correctly get `bool(false), int(8)` as inputs. So it's even type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
bool all_not_equal(T a, const vector<T>& others) {
    for (auto& other : others) {
        if (a == other) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Try to avoid macros in situations like this. Also name your function to reflect your logic. `equalTo` implies you are returning true if all are equal to `a`

Comment: You may even use `return std::none_of(others.begin(), others.end(), [&](const T&x) {return a == x;});`.

Comment: You may pass vector by const reference.